# Plot Y against X as X is a time range for each value of y

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a simple graph to no avail!

Instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPgJm.jpg) the best i can come up with is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo3WS.jpg) one

Even [this simple one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml5Hw.jpg) isn't working, the main problem is I need the line to go just horizontal say for 5 mins at a constant y value then the value changes and I want it to go constant for another 10 mins or so. Something like this:

Y = [5, 10, 11, 6]

X = [0-10mins, 10mins-25mins, 25-45mins, 45-50mins]

plot Y on against X

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a step function. Please note that here I added 0 to X and 5 to Y in the beginning so as to have the correct first step span from 0 to 10

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [0, 10, 25, 45, 50]
Y = [5, 5, 10, 11, 6]

plt.step(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: If you have unsorted X-array and you want to sum up the X values, you can use `cumsum` from NumPy. The main idea here is to first insert 0 to your list and then convert to array followed by cumulative summing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = [6, 27, 9, 19]
X.insert(0,0)
X = np.cumsum(X)

Y = [5, 5, 10, 11, 6]

plt.step(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment but another complication is i provided an ideal case. My data is not arranged in increasing order on the x axis. I want it to automatically sum up. For example, now i have on the x axis [6, 27, 9, 19]

Comment: Okay i added the times manually but maybe there is a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I propose a simple loop solution like below. In order to make the figure nicer, you can specify different colors, texts and so on.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ------------------
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
# --------------------
xdata=[0,10,25,45,50]
ydata=[5,10,11,6];
colors=['b','b','b','b']
# --------------------
fig=plt.figure();
ax=fig.add_subplot(111);
for i in range(len(xdata)-1):
    xloc=0.5*(xdata[i+1]+xdata[i])
    xwidth=xdata[i+1]-xdata[i];
    ax.bar(xloc,ydata[i],width=xwidth,color=colors[i]);
plt.show()
```

Comment: This case  is working but on trying it out with my samples it's not producing the actual result. Here is a picture https://pp.userapi.com/c850616/v850616739/16d22e/yaqlrB3ohmg.jpg

Also the time i have is already the width length so i edited accordingly but now it's plotting in increasing order rather than cummulative and has exchange the position of the second and third elements

Comment: @JKL, I do not know the values of your data, so cannot give explanation why it does not work with your data. Could you provide the values of Flow_Spacer, Flow_lead and so on?

Comment: The time is the same as the time in the data frame and the flow rate is same as the flow of each as well